# VictoriaMetrics / Grafana not showing data from a period in the middle of range but shows up data when zoomed in

Tags: grafana, promql, victoriametrics

We have been attempting to backfill 6 months of data into VictoriaMetrics. VictoriaMetrics is set up in a cluster with 2 vmstorage nodes and 1 vminsert and 1 vmselect instance. Everything went smoothly until data stopped showing up grafana after a specific date. Our import script was still running without an error. Checking the logs for vminsert and 2 vmstorage nodes there's no error. Then data started appearing at the end of the range.

So, a big chunk of the data is missing on Grafana. But **sometimes** zooming in reveals some of the data that doesn't show up on a higher time range. After double-checking the vmstorage logs seems like partitions are not the same on each node. and one of the nodes is missing the latest partition.

**Logs from Storage Node 1**

```
2022-12-02T00:21:22.521Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:200    creating a partition "2022_06" with smallPartsPath="/storage/data/small/2022_06", bigPartsPath="/storage/data/big/2022_06"
2022-12-02T00:21:24.259Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:216    partition "2022_06" has been created
2022-12-02T13:56:23.722Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:200    creating a partition "2022_07" with smallPartsPath="/storage/data/small/2022_07", bigPartsPath="/storage/data/big/2022_07"
2022-12-02T13:56:26.533Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:216    partition "2022_07" has been created
2022-12-03T01:24:45.721Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:200    creating a partition "2022_08" with smallPartsPath="/storage/data/small/2022_08", bigPartsPath="/storage/data/big/2022_08"
2022-12-03T01:24:46.900Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:216    partition "2022_08" has been created
2022-12-03T17:57:02.525Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:200    creating a partition "2022_09" with smallPartsPath="/storage/data/small/2022_09", bigPartsPath="/storage/data/big/2022_09"
2022-12-03T17:57:03.713Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:216    partition "2022_09" has been created
2022-12-04T07:08:51.722Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:1305   merged 18251 rows across 18251 blocks in 37.328 seconds at 488 rows/sec to "/storage/data/small/2022_09/18251_18251_20220928180000.000_20220928180000.000_172D5A35BF48B011"; sizeBytes: 250837
2022-12-04T08:41:28.530Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:200    creating a partition "2022_10" with smallPartsPath="/storage/data/small/2022_10", bigPartsPath="/storage/data/big/2022_10"
2022-12-04T08:41:31.022Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:216    partition "2022_10" has been created
2022-12-04T21:22:29.569Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/mergeset/table.go:1027  merged 24870725 items across 28659 blocks in 37.205 seconds at 668480 items/sec to "/storage/indexdb/172CAC7059FB5EB3/24860954_28638_172CAC71E7BD8BD0"; sizeBytes: 331467849
2022-12-04T22:37:55.719Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:200    creating a partition "2022_11" with smallPartsPath="/storage/data/small/2022_11", bigPartsPath="/storage/data/big/2022_11"
2022-12-04T22:37:56.406Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:216    partition "2022_11" has been created
2022-12-05T00:39:45.097Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:1305   merged 199154 rows across 199154 blocks in 30.426 seconds at 6545 rows/sec to "/storage/data/small/2022_11/199154_113352_20221104180000.000_20221106180000.000_172DB81E235772F4"; sizeBytes: 1909359
2022-12-05T03:29:28.254Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:1305   merged 211814 rows across 211814 blocks in 30.355 seconds at 6977 rows/sec to "/storage/data/small/2022_11/211814_114004_20221108180000.000_20221110180000.000_172DB81E235773BF"; sizeBytes: 1891824
2022-12-05T16:34:53.329Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:200    creating a partition "2022_12" with smallPartsPath="/storage/data/small/2022_12", bigPartsPath="/storage/data/big/2022_12"
2022-12-05T16:34:54.324Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:216    partition "2022_12" has been created
```

**Logs from Storage Node 2**

```
2022-12-02T00:21:22.523Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:200    creating a partition "2022_06" with smallPartsPath="/storage/data/small/2022_06", bigPartsPath="/storage/data/big/2022_06"
2022-12-02T00:21:23.985Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:216    partition "2022_06" has been created
2022-12-02T13:56:23.727Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:200    creating a partition "2022_07" with smallPartsPath="/storage/data/small/2022_07", bigPartsPath="/storage/data/big/2022_07"
2022-12-02T13:56:26.533Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:216    partition "2022_07" has been created
2022-12-03T01:24:45.724Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:200    creating a partition "2022_08" with smallPartsPath="/storage/data/small/2022_08", bigPartsPath="/storage/data/big/2022_08"
2022-12-03T01:24:46.900Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:216    partition "2022_08" has been created
2022-12-03T17:57:02.517Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:200    creating a partition "2022_09" with smallPartsPath="/storage/data/small/2022_09", bigPartsPath="/storage/data/big/2022_09"
2022-12-03T17:57:03.713Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:216    partition "2022_09" has been created
2022-12-04T07:08:23.316Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:1305   merged 23345 rows across 23345 blocks in 33.611 seconds at 694 rows/sec to "/storage/data/small/2022_09/23345_23345_20220928180000.000_20220928180000.000_172D5A35BF445C06"; sizeBytes: 338817
2022-12-04T08:41:28.524Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:200    creating a partition "2022_10" with smallPartsPath="/storage/data/small/2022_10", bigPartsPath="/storage/data/big/2022_10"
2022-12-04T08:41:31.022Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:216    partition "2022_10" has been created
2022-12-04T22:37:55.725Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:200    creating a partition "2022_11" with smallPartsPath="/storage/data/small/2022_11", bigPartsPath="/storage/data/big/2022_11"
2022-12-04T22:37:56.406Z    info    VictoriaMetrics/lib/storage/partition.go:216    partition "2022_11" has been created
```

- What is the issue here?
- Why does the data sometimes show up when zoomed in?
- Is there a data mismatch between the nodes that sometimes show up based on which node got routed to?

Comment: One possible cause: `Max data points` in the query settings is set to a number smaller than the number of results you have, you could try increasing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely you need to reset response cache at every `vmselect` node after the backfilling process is complete. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#backfilling) for details.

Comment: awesome. turns out the script was calling `/internal/resetRollupResultCache` the `vminsert` node and even then with the wrong path. now all data is showing up.